# Newly added objects dont appear on render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, visibility

I have started a forest scene with a small log cabin. For a long time everything was normal until today. When I try to add any object to the scene (Be it an instance of an already existing object or something completely new, like a suzanne head) dont appear in my render. They do show up in the viewport in all four modes, but not in the final render. Doesnt have to do anything with the material since there aren't any to begin with. Any idea why this happens and how to fix it? I added two pictures below showing the viewport with the corresponding cycles render.

[image: Here the picture of the viewport (Cube added for demonstration purposes):]

[image: Here you can see the corresponding render (Low res due to 2MB upload limit):]

Comment: Most likely the object is added in the active collection that is not enabled for rendering.

Comment: Thought about that too, but thats not the case. Its in the same collection as the cabin itself, which is clearly visible in the render

Comment: well, can you upload your file here with key parts included? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/